# Given a SHA-256 message block, is it possible to undo the transformation of the internal state?

Tags: hash, one-way-function

Consider the transformation described in [section 6.2 of RFC4634](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634#section-6.2) ("US Secure Hash Algorithms (SHA and HMAC-SHA)"). Given the message block `M(i)`, and hence the message schedule `W`, as well as the output of the block function `H(i)`, how hard should I expect computing `H(i-1)` to be?

Interestingly, the 64 "rounds" are easily reversible for this set of knowns and unknowns, but the final addition makes using this fact not trivial.

Comment: Do you still wonder after reading on the [Davies-Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies%E2%80%93Meyer) construction of One-Way Functions?

Comment: @fgrieu My claim; mining...

Comment: @fgrieu After reading that section three times, I still don't understand what you're hinting at. As far as I can see, this being possible would not damage any security requirements of hashing functions.

Comment: @kelalaka I don't see how this could be useful for mining -- the goal there is to find the message, and that's been studied thoroughly already.

Comment: There were a mining people tried to revers the hash algorithm. The first target for a hash function should be finding collisions not finding the pre-image see [Joux's paper]{https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2004/31520306/multicollisions.pdf}

Comment: @kelalaka I'm not trying to find collisions or preimages. I'm essentially trying to "unappend", which is not something that hash functions try to resist according to the definitions I could find.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That would give you widely known constants, which is definitely something that hashes don't need to resist.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Maybe it's possible to generate preimages or collisions given an "unappender oracle" in polynomial time, but I don't see how it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this 'unappend' operation is effectively infeasible for the SHA-256 hash compression operation; there is no known way that is less expensive than brute force.

Such an 'unappend' operation would reduce the time taken to generate preimages from $2^{256}$ to $2^{129}$ hash compression operations (assuming that the unappend operation is as cheap as the forward hash compression operation).  This would be done via a meet-in-the-middle attack, where in the most straight-forward implementation, you generate one list of $2^{128}$ intermediate states (from $2^{128}$ prefixes), and you generate a second list of $2^{128}$ intermediate states (from $2^{128}$ postfixes; starting from the target hash, you use the unappend operation), and search for a common value in the two lists.